# Getting "Running the docker.exe login command failed." while trying to publish to Azure container registery

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, .net-core, azure-container-registry

I am trying to publish my .Net core app docker image to Azure Container Registry using Visual Studio 2019.

It was working fine, but suddenly I started to see the following error:

> Publish has encountered an error. Running the docker.exe login command
> failed.
>
> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use
> --password-stdin.Error response from daemon: Get https://app.azurecr.io:443/v2/: unauthorized: authentication
> required
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp768.tmp"

When running the following CMD command:

```
docker login https://app.azurecr.io
```

I am getting:

> Authenticating with existing credentials...
>
> Login Succeeded

I restarted Visual Studio and Docker, And I am running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Anyone ran into similar issue?

Answer (score 8):

The solution was to:

1- run the cmd command:

`docker login https://app.azurecr.io:443` **port included**

2- providing username and password again.

3- Publish from Visual Studio.

Note:-  'app' in the above url is the name of the registry

Comment: no matter what it is now giving error message:

Publish has encountered an error.
Running the docker.exe login command failed.

WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unauthorized: incorrect username or password

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location: ...

Comment: ultimately worked using `az login --name xxx --expose-token` and using the token with the `--password` option.

`docker login myrepo.azurecr.io:443 -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --password %TOKEN%`

could not get it to work using `--password-stdin` method, but the `:443` is necessary.

Comment: almost a year later with vs2022: same problem, same solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was solved. But I deleted the publish profile, then added it again. when I did that, it asked me to sign in to azure again. This fixed it for me.

Comment: yep, delete profile, recreate with credentials worked for me also

Comment: Good call. I just had to sign out of my MSDN account in VS, then sign back in, and the credentials error went away.

Answer (score 1):

At the top right of Visual Studio click on your signed in user and log in again.

[image]